# Using Ubuntu as a file server and VM host on refurb server hardware

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, raid, nas

I've been planning to set up a NAS in my office, and this idea has been subject to a bit of feature creep. I was going to get a Synology, then I saw how much refurbished server hardware I could get for the price of one of those, and you can already see where this is heading …

I'm considering buying a ProLiant DL380 Gen9, and I'm thinking I could use it both as a NAS and a host for a Windows VM for running some misc Win-only software, as we don't have any Windows workstations at the office.

I've consireded TrueNAS, but I take it it's not very good at running VMs, and I've considered UnRaid, but I take it its "RAID" implementation is quite slow. I'd like to my NAS to be fast enough to edit video files (on a 10GbE LAN). I also considered usint Proxmox with OpenMediaVault, but that's rather unfamiliar territory, and getting it to work with snapshots, etc, seems like a bit of a hassle. so what I'm contemplating now is simply running Ubuntu on the server to do the SMB file serving and snapshot handling.

Setting up a network share etc is rather trivial, but I'm uncertain about what file system to use. I think my options are either ZFS, BTRFS with software RAID or BTRFS with hardware RAID. Any good arguments in favour of either of those? Which one would be easiest to expand with more disks later on? I'll be starting off with 3 or 4 disks and would prefer maximum performance with a bit of redundancy – which I think sounds like RAID5. I take it the ZFS equivalent, RAIDZ1, isn't the best performing alternative, and ZFS RAID10 seems a bit complex. Is it worth the hassle?

As for the VMs, I'm familiar with the GUI way of setting up VMs on Ubuntu, but I'd like to get GPU pass-through to Windows, which apparently is also a bit complex, and I have no experience with it. As far as I can gather, the server I'm looking at does IOMMU, but I couldn't find much info on it other than a forum thread from 2016 where someone had difficulty enabling it on Ubuntu. Am I asking for trouble going this route?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Are you asking about ZFS, VMs, or the HP ProLiant DL380? 

Comment: Yeah, this post was s bit of a ramble, sorry! I'm mainly looking for recommendations on file system and RAID topology choices, and also wondering whether I can expect GPU passthrough to work on this machine. Also, (implicitly!), I'm wondering whether Ubuntu is a good choice of host OS.